# No refresh of static variables after language change

Tags: c#

I am having the following resources file:

```
public static string Msg = "My Message is" + MyProgram.Properties.Resources.MsgContent + ".";
```

From the main thread, I am changing the language during runtime and retrieve the variable value later on. The static variable Msg does not come up with the right language concatenation. 
To correct the problem, I was forced to create the below function that I call each time I need to change the culture:

```
public static void RefreshVariablesWithLanguage()
{
  Msg = "My Message is" + MyProgram.Properties.Resources.MsgContent + ".";
}
```

Is there any more elegant way to make the static variable to re-consider the language before returning the value.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of a method, you could use a property like that:

```
public string MsgContent => MyProgram.Properties.Resources.MsgContent;
```

and you can just use it this way;

```
public static string Msg = "My Message is" + MsgContent + ".";
```

Comment: @JonSkeet yes you are right, this would be the more elegant and short way. I will update my answer, thx.

Comment: sorry for the delayed answer and thanks for the elegant proposal. My resource class is static so I can use the property approach.